# Random blank pages on Safari when developing webapp

Tags: php, apache, safari

I've been experiencing a safari problem while building a web application. The screen goes completely blank (white) and refreshing won't help. Going to another page on the site gives the same problem. Then magically, after a little while, everything goes back to normal and pages are rendered correctly!

This started happening around the same time that I *SUSPECT* my hosting automatically upgraded from PHP 5.2.x to 5.3 (all of a sudden, we got 'deprecated function' errors and the error settings and handling were unchanged)

I also have to mention that this doesn't happen in our dev environment (PHP 5.2.9, Apache 2)

### Settings

Safari 4.0.2 and the latest one (don't know the version)
Server side: PHP 5.3, MySQL 5.0.90, Apache is cPanel Easy Apache v3.2.0

Does anyone know why this is happening at all or know how to fix it?

Comment: Does that only happen when using your web application?

Comment: Does it do the same thing with other browsers, or just Safari?

Comment: Do you have access to the apache logs (access.log and error.log)? And if so are there message that might be related to the problem?

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for all of your messages. 
Yes, as far as I can tell, it only happens when using my web application. 
It hasn't happened with any browsers, other than Safari.
Yes, I have access to the Apache logs and they look perfectly normal, even when I look at them right after a failed request!!!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it happens with other browsers as well as safari it is probably an error message generated but not displayed. Depending on your code these can be time dependent.

If you have an error log file on your server check it's content.

You should also set up a PHP 5.3 development environment as quickly as possible. There are things that can go wrong when upgrading from 5.2. to 5.3 (see [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php) and yes, you can get angry at your provider, the PHP site does not advice an upgrade without a code check).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response.

As I mentioned above, I haven't seen it happen with any other browsers; just Safari. 

Setting up a 5.3 env is a very good idea that I didn't think of. Thanks. I'll try to do that ASAP. 

Yeah, I don't understand. When I mentioned it to them, they acted as if it's perfectly routine...! I can't understand how I can constantly keep my application ahead of their "curve" when their cpanel configuration randomly decides to upgrade the version of the *language* in which the app is written. Anyway, I digress.

Comment: Also, sometimes followed/preceded by this strange behaviour, some page resources such as images/libraries do not load and the page is not fully loaded.